# iPhone SDK: How to detect a row-hit while in the editing mode?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, row

I've looked everywhere and I can't find it.

I have a UITableView that contain rows of "checkmark" cells.

The user clicks on a row to check/uncheck it.
(It works!!!!)

But I also want to allow the user to EDIT the data on that row.

... so I have an "EDIT" button at the top.  The user hits it and is allowed to DELETE any
rows.   (That works too!!!!)

But how do I also detect a "tap" on that row.

Where is there some kind of a didSelectRowAtIndexPathWhileInEditMode ????

(Is that really the best way to do this:  Allow "selections", and "deletions", and "editing" of each row?)

Answer (score 7):

You should switch on **allowsSelectionDuringEditing** for UITableView from code or Interface Builder